# Passing an element of a collection in the query builder

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I would like to make a second request with the id obtained in the previous request.

I have 3 tables:

- organization
- users
- follow_organization (relationship table)

I would like to obtain the number of occurrences in the `follow_organization` table by passing the id of the organization previously obtained.

```php
$organization = DB::table('organizations')->where('name', $name)->first();
$followers = DB::table('follow_organizations')->where('organization_id', $organization)->count();
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> Object of class `stdClass` could not be converted to string.

I understood the problem, I pass a table while the query builder waits for a string.
But I can't find the solution to this problem despite the tons of answers I've read on the internet.

Comment: You need to pass the `id` from the organization to the `where` clause, at the moment you are passing the whole object: `DB::table('follow_organizations')->where('organization_id', $organization->id)->count();`

Comment: Thank's @Remul !
I didn't have the solution to just pass the id instead of the whole collection!
I can't put your comment in "solution" but it is the right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are passing the whole organization object into the where clause, but you only need the `id`.

To access the `id` property you can use `$organization->id`

```php
DB::table('follow_organizations')->where('organization_id', $organization->id)->count();
```

[Setting and Getting Property Values](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/sdo.sample.getset.php)